# R : How to find the location of the max value in a raster?

Tags: r, raster

How can I find a location of max. value in a raster using R?
I know the max. value of the raster, but I need to find its location.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's try with a toy raster as follows:

```
library(raster)
r = raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
r[] = runif(100,0,10)
```

Then the position (index) of the maximum is found using

```
idx = which.max(r)
```

And from thhe index position to the coordinates of the cell

```
pos = xyFromCell(r,idx)
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: I think you gave an answer but I am still getting NA ??? I will study more based on your example. Thanks, Nahm

Comment: Yes, it works.                                                     idx <- which.max(RAD.all[[168]] == Rad.all.max)                    pos <- xyFromCell(RAD.all[[168]],idx)                        Thanks, Nahm

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 'mat' is your raster/matrix:

```
which(mat == max(mat), arr.ind=TRUE)
```